# Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на исходник (на C#) иерархической PropertyGrid (без CollectionEditor) для WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid

Привет. Кто-нибудь, дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на исходник иерархической PropertyGrid for WPF (я разрабатываю приложение на C# WPF MVVM, используя Prism 6). Мне нужна иерархическая PropertyGrid, в которой нет диплодока, называющегося CollectionEditor. Т.е. элементы в этой PropertyGrid должны располагаться в следующем порядке:

```
- ROOT

      - GROUP

             ITEM                           значение элемента

             ITEM                           значение элемента

             - GROUP

                  - GROUP

                          ITEM            значение элемента

                          ITEM            значение элемента

                  ITEM                    значение элемента

      + GROUP

      ITEM                                  значение элемента

      ITEM                                  значение элемента

    . . . . . . . . .
```

и т.д.

Если група развернута (т.е. показывается её внутреннее содержимое), то слева от её имени стоит знак '-', показывающий, что группу можно свернуть, а если свёрнута, то - знак '+', показывающий, что групу можно развернуть и посмотреть её содержимое. Количество элементов и групп, содержащих элементы, а так же глубина вложенности групп и элементов определяются только во время работы приложения (в design-time об этом неизвестно). В качестве источника данных для такой PropertyGrid, я намериваюсь использовать ObservableCollection, содержащую иерархические данные. Определения класса Group (для GROUP) и класса Register (для ITEM) вы можете посмотреть в моём посте на Stackoverflow по ссылке: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058259/why-is-invalideoperationexception-thrown-when-i-try-to-serialize-to-xml-an-obser . Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: https://wpg.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WPG/PropertyGrid.cs